# How to install Moto drivers for ADB

Tags: 14.04, android, adb

As stated above, I want to install moto drivers on my laptop thats running ubuntu 14.04. I have adb installed but im not sure how to install my drivers.

http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

At the bottom it says how to do it but im new to linux any help woulld be appreciated.

Comment: It would be better if you mention what your final goal is and maybe it'd be better to ask in android stack exchange

Comment: my goal is to be able to have my laptop recognize my phone so i can use adb commands like pulling logcats for example

Comment: You shouldn't need any additional drivers to use adb with your phone on Ubuntu (I have been able to use adb with my S4 without any additional drivers). Just try running an adb command (`adb devices` is a good place to start) with your phone plugged in.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your computer into developer mode and enable USB debugging.

Steps to take:

Goto:
  Settings > About phone > Build number

Tap it 7 times.
You'll enter developer mode.

The go back to Settings > 'Developer settings' and turn on 'USB debugging'.   Your device should then show up when you run 'adb  devices'.

Comment: I figured this as well, but my device is not showing. Any tips?

Comment: Make sure your USB cable supports data transfers, the phone should announce that USB debugging is activated already when connecting to the PC when the cable is working

Comment: my computer says the phone is unsupported to flash